# Выравнивание текста

Tags: html, css, вёрстка

http://vk.cc/3dQWma Как сделать, чтобы текст был на одном уровне?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Уберите `padding-right` у класса `.dl`. Из-за этого отступа суммарная ширина блоков `.dl` и `.dr` не 100%, а 100% + 3px, поэтому второй элемент не влазит в ширину родительского блока и съезжает ниже. Вообще, в такой структуре страницы как-то сами собой напрашиваются таблицы, а не `span`'ы с `float`'ами. Ну, или хотя-бы с `display: table-row;` и `display: table-cell;`.

Ещё один вариант: добавьте блокам `.dl` и `.dr` свойство `box-sizing: border-box;`, тогда `padding`'и будут включаться в ширину блока.